# Object reference unassigning itself at runtime in UNITY

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to reference the grid object which contains a script that has my inventorygrid class. I'm referencing from another script attached to the ui camera.

[image]

Its assigned like this:

[image]

I'm just trying to reference it like this:

```
    public class InventoryController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private InventoryGrid selectedInventoryGrid;
 
    private void Update()
    {
        if (selectedInventoryGrid = null)
        {
            Debug.Log("InventoryGrid IS null.");
            return;
        }
 
 
        selectedInventoryGrid.GetTileGridPosition(Input.mousePosition);
    }
}
```

However, when trying to run the referenced class and method, I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.". I've noticed that the "Selected Inventory Grid" that I've assigned just unassigns itself when I run the game.

Comment: I don't use Unity so forgive my ignorance but are you sure that that UI sets the value of that private field? It wouldn't in a normal C# app but I realise that Unity works a bit differently in some way.

Comment: @jmcilhinney that's not how unity works, all serialised feilds are modifiable from the editor.

Answer (score 3):

```
selectedInventoryGrid = null
```

It should be

```
selectedInventoryGrid == null
```

I was setting it null without realising.

Answer (score -1):

You have two issues. First is already mentioned by @DeveloperLewis.

```
 if (selectedInventoryGrid = null)
    {
        Debug.Log("InventoryGrid IS null.");
        return;
    }
```

If you are checking for null, it should be "==" not "=".

Second issue is this field:

```
    [SerializeField] private InventoryGrid selectedInventoryGrid;
```

I think that some versions of Unity have a bug (or it worked all the time like this?) that they drop the reference if your field is PRIVATE but has [SerializeField] attribute assigned to it.

Solution is that, you need to make that field PUBLIC.

```
public InventoryGrid selectedInventoryGrid;
```

Comment: The first part of this is correct but the second part is definitely wrong. Unity can absolutely serialise private fields and the pattern is considered canonical/best practice. Exposing this as public is terrible advice.

Comment: @rootpanthera It is getting unassigned because the questioner is making it `null` in the `if` check so changing `selectedInventoryGrid = null` to `selectedInventoryGrid == null` should solve questioner's issue.